# How can I access Microk8s in Read only mode?

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s

I would like to read state of K8s using µK8s, but I don't want to have rights to modify anything. How to achieve this?

The following will give me full access:

```
microk8s.kubectl  Insufficient permissions to access MicroK8s. You can either try again with sudo or add the user digital to the 'microk8s' group:

   sudo usermod -a -G microk8s digital    sudo chown -f -R digital ~/.kube

The new group will be available on the user's next login.
```

Comment: Changing ownership of the config file won't give you much when it comes to limiting your cluster roles/permissions. As you can see in step 2 [here](https://microk8s.io/docs) doing what you described in question is completely normal. For cluster permission fine tuning you'll need to change/config RBAC rules. Lastly, having clearly described goal will definitely help with providing you some solution.

Comment: In my company there is a policy that programmers cannot modify anything on production (IMHO sane). While we are migrating to K8S, we want to enable read-only access like checking status / deployment etc for programmers, but all changes must go through DEV-OPS teams. Only DEV-OPS team have `sudo` and rights to modify anything.

Comment: .. on Unix/Linux we can just set appropriate file/directory access permission - just `rx`, decrease shell limits (like max memory/open file descriptors), decrease  process priority (`nice -19`).   We are looking for similar solution for K8S . Of course there is a fashion not to give terminal access to production systems and use all the Gui/Web tools for K8S, but access by terminal is an additional check for teams lead developers to check if everything is correct.

Comment: Specially we work on a low-latency (or latency sensitive) systems and we must look for K8S's nodes with some attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> on Unix/Linux we can just set appropriate file/directory access
> permission - just `rx`, decrease shell limits (like max memory/open
> file descriptors), decrease process priority (`nice -19`). We are
> looking for similar solution for K8S

This kind of solutions in Kubernetes are handled via [RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) (Role-based access control).  RBAC prevents unauthorized users from viewing or modifying the cluster state. Because the API server exposes a REST interface, users perform actions by sending HTTP requests to the server. Users authenticate themselves by including credentials in the request (an authentication token, username and password, or a client certificate).

As for REST clients you get `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`,`DELETE` etc. These are send to specific URL paths that represents specific REST API resources (Pods, Services, Deployments and so).

RBAC auth is configured with two groups:

- Roles and ClusterRoles - this specify which actions/verbs can be performed
- RoleBinding and ClusterRoleBindings - this bind the above roles to a user, group or service account.

As you might already find out the [ClusterRole](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#clusterrole-example) is the one your might be looking for. This will allow to restrict specific user or group against the cluster.
In the example below we are creating `ClusterRole` that can only list pods. The namespace is omitted since ClusterRoles are not namepsaced.

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: pod-viewer
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["list"]
```

This permission has to be bound then via `ClusterRoleBinding` :

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
# This cluster role binding allows anyone in the "manager" group to list pods in any namespace.
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: list-pods-global
subjects:
- kind: Group
  name: manager # Name is case sensitive
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: pod-viewer
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Because you don't have the enough permissions on your own you have to reach out to appropriate person who manage those to create user for you that has the `ClusterRole: View`. View role should be predefined already in cluster ( `kubectl get clusterrole view`)

If you wish to read more [Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/) explains well its whole concept of authorization.